# Mapping Class object to generic object

Tags: java, spring, generics

So I have an abstract entity `Compound` and a abstract Service `CompoundService<T extends Compound>`.

There is another service class that needs access to any implementation of `CompoundService<T extends Compound>` (arbitary number, implementation unknown at compile time). This is required in 1 specific method and that method can takes a class argument `Class<? extends Compound>`.

The question is how to I type-safely map this class to the according service class?

Something like `Map<Class<? extends Compound>, CompoundService<? extends Compound>>` does not work as I require the generic parameter of `CompoundService` to be specific and not a wildcard.

I'm not sure how to explain this. But `compoundService.getById(compoundId)` returns a `Compound` instance of type `T` or `compoundService.save(compound)` requires `compound` to be of type `T`. This means that

```
Map<Class<? extends Compound>, CompoundService<? extends Compound>> services = //...;
CompoundService<T> compoundService = services.get(compoundClass);
```

does not work as  `CompoundService<? extends Compound>>` can not be cast to `CompoundService<T>`.

Hm, not sure if that helped. The issue is the mapping of Class object `Class<? extends Compound>` to this "types" service class `CompoundService<? extends Compound>`.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want to do:

```
abstract class Compound { }

class Compound1 extends Compound { }

abstract class CompoundService<T extends Compound> {
    ...
}

class Compound1Service extends CompoundService<Compound1> {
    ...
}

public class Test {

    static Map<Class<? extends Compound>, CompoundService<? extends Compound>> serviceMap = new HashMap<Class<? extends Compound>, CompoundService<? extends Compound>>();

    public static <T extends Compound> void main(String[] args) {
        serviceMap.put(Compound1.class, new Compound1Service());
        CompoundService<Compound1> service = getServiceFromMap(Compound1.class);
        System.out.println(service.getClass());
    }

    public static <T extends Compound> CompoundService<T> getServiceFromMap(Class<T> clazz) {
        return(CompoundService<T>)serviceMap.get(clazz);
    }

}
```

I don't think you will get better than this and avoid the cast due to type erasure